# Solving equation of the type $ -1 = \cos x - a x \sin x $

Tags: calculus

I have the equation
$$ -1 = \cos x - a x \sin x $$
where, $a$ is a constant, $x$ is a real variable and taken in the range $0<x<\pi$. When I solve it by simply rearranging the terms, I end up with
$$ \frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}=\cot \frac{x}{2}=a x. $$

However, the correct answer is supposed to give both
$$\cot \frac{x}{2}=a x,$$
$$\cos \frac{x}{2}=0.$$

I am not sure how the latter was found. I must be missing something. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You divided by $\sin x$. You need to check if $\sin x=0$ can be a solution. It is, if $\cos x=-1$. This is $x=\pm \pi, \pm 3\pi,...$, which is equivalent to $\cos\frac x2=0$. However, for $0<x<\pi$ you don't have the second solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your "real" equation is:
$$
1+\cos x=a x\sin x\implies2\cos^2\frac x2=2ax \cos\frac x2\sin\frac x2
\implies 2\cos\frac x2\left(\cos\frac x2-ax\sin\frac x2\right)=0.
$$
This equation has two solutions: $\cos\frac x2=0$ and $\cos\frac x2-ax\sin\frac x2=0$

Your mistake was that you canceled $\cos\frac x2$ without considering the possiblity that it can be zero.

Answer (score 0):

If we discrad the trivial solution (as explained in previous answers), the problem is effectively to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=\cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-ax$$ which will not show any explicit solutions. There will not be any problem with numerical method.

But we can build *approximations*. For example, using Taylor expansion
$$\frac{\cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{x}=\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{x^2}{360}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ which is a more than decent approximation (just plot the lhs and rhson the same graph for $0\leq x\leq \pi$).

Neglecting the higher order terms
$$a=\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{x^2}{360}\implies x^4+60(1+6a)x^2-720=0$$ which is a quadratic in $x^2$ and then

$$x_{\text{est}}=\sqrt{6 \left( \sqrt{15(60 a^2+20 a+3)}-30 a-5\right)}$$

For example, using $a=12.345$, this would give $x_{\text{est}}= 0.399806370$ while the "exact" solution, obtained by Newton method, is $x=0.399806343$.

Using $a=0.12345$, this would give $x_{\text{est}}= 2.54763$ while the "exact" solution, obtained by Newton method, is $x=2.53501$.

Now, trying to have better estimates, using the first iterate of an high order iterative method starting with $x_0=0$, one can propose
$$x_{\text{est}}=\sqrt{\frac{220 \left(22680 a^4+15120 a^3+4158 a^2+558 a+31\right)}{2494800 a^5+2079000
   a^4+748440 a^3+145200 a^2+15202 a+691}}$$ which seems to be decent as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & x_{\text{est}} & x_{\text{exact}}\\
 1 & \color{red} {1.3065423}80219720 & 
                  1.306542374188806\\
 2 & \color{red} {0.96018887}4044812 & 
                  0.960188873914783 \\
 3 & \color{red} {0.7944961284}50111 & 
                  0.794496128438359 \\
 4 & \color{red} {0.69270825340}9536 & 
                  0.692708253407499 \\
 5 & \color{red} {0.62210569640}1108 & 
                  0.622105696400595 \\
 6 & \color{red} {0.569452885113}318 & 
                  0.569452885113153 \\
 7 & \color{red} {0.5282417875158}91 & 
                  0.528241787515829 \\
 8 & \color{red} {0.494850930368852} & 
 0.494850930368852 
\end{array}
\right)$$